# How to run rails background jobs in a sequential manner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I am calling a background job from my controller to fetch around 1000 entries from the database and work on it. However I want to call this job for every new entry in the database. How can I execute this in a sequential manner? As in, if one entry is executing the job, other one should wait for it and then perform the task.

Comment: Are you using some kind of queue management? If yes, then this is already being done. Queues are FIFO, so when something is added by the controller, the entry is queued.

Comment: I am not aware much about this. Its `queue_as :default` written in my code. What should I do to use some queue management?

Comment: Can you post your code where you are calling this background job?